# How to find out component-path

Tags: wicket

I use junit to assert the existing of wicket components:

```
wicketTester.assertComponent("dev1WicketId:dev2WicketId:formWicketId", Form.class);
```

This works for some forms. For complex structure, it is defficult to find out the path of the form by searching all html files. Is there any method how to find out the path easy?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have the component you can call `#getPageRelativePath()`. E.g.

```
// Supposing c is a component that has been added to the page.
// Returns the full path to the component relative to the page, e.g., "path:to:label"
String pathToComponent = c.getPageRelativePath();
```

You can get the children of a markup container by using the `visitChildren()` method. The following example shows how to get all the `Form`s from a page.

```
List<Form> list = new ArrayList<Form<?>>();
Page page = wicketTester.getLastRenderedPage();
for (Form form : page.visitChildren(Form.class)) {
    list.add(form);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

An easy way to get those is to call [`getDebugSettings().setOutputComponentPath(true);`](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/settings/IDebugSettings.html#setOutputComponentPath%28boolean%29) when initializing your application. This will make Wicket to output these paths to the generated HTML as an attribute on every component-bound tag.

It's recommended to only enable this on debug mode, though:

```
public class WicketApplication extends WebApplication {
    @Override
    public void init() {
        super.init();

        if (getConfigurationType() == RuntimeConfigurationType.DEVELOPMENT) {
            getDebugSettings().setOutputComponentPath(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it does not work with last version of wicket

Answer (score 1):

Extending the RJo's answer.

It seems that the method `page.visitChildren(<Class>)` is deprecated (Wicket 6), so with an IVisitor it can be :

```
protected String findPathComponentOnLastRenderedPage(final String idComponent) {
    final Page page = wicketTester.getLastRenderedPage();
    return page.visitChildren(Component.class, new IVisitor<Component, String>() {
        @Override
        public void component(final Component component, final IVisit<String> visit) {
            if (component.getId().equals(idComponent)) {
                visit.stop(component.getPageRelativePath());
            }
        }
    });
}
```